# Error al hacer un if con &&

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de poner 2 horas con strings pasandolas a split y cuando quiero comprobar que se ha metido entre 0 y 23 sea correcto y si no me lo pida de nuevo, pero no me lo pilla

```
package primeraevaluacion;

import utilidades.Entrada;

public class Ejerciciodos {

    /*Ejercicio pides 2 horas, si la primera hora es 
     * superior a la otra indicas 1, 
     * si las dos 2 iguales 0, si la segunda hora es mas grande -1*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean correcto=false;
        String hora1;
        String hora2;
        
        String[] horauno;
        String [] horados;
        
        int h1,m1,s1;
        int h2,m2,s2;
        
        System.out.println("Hora 1 ");
        hora1=Entrada.cadena();
        horauno=hora1.split(":");
        System.out.println("Hora 2 ");
        hora2=Entrada.cadena();
        horados=hora2.split(":");
        
        
            
            
            
            do {
                h1=Integer.parseInt(horauno[0]);
                if (h1>=0 && h1<=23  ) {
                    
                    correcto=true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("La hora (1) tiene que estar comprendida entre 0 y 23");
                    h1=Entrada.entero();
                }
            } while (correcto!=true);
            
            m1=Integer.parseInt(horauno[1]);
            s1=Integer.parseInt(horauno[2]);
            
            
            do {
                h2=Integer.parseInt(horados[0]);
                if (h2>23 && h2<0) {
                    System.out.println("La hora (2) tiene que estar comprendida entre 0 y 23");
                    h2=Entrada.entero();
                    correcto=false;
                } else {
                    correcto=true;
                }
            } while (correcto!=true);
            
            m2=Integer.parseInt(horados[1]);
            s2=Integer.parseInt(horados[2]);
        
            
            if (h1==h2 && m1==m2 && s1==s2) {
                System.out.println(0);
            } else if (h1>h2) {
                System.out.println(1);
            } else {
                System.out.println(-1);
            }
        
    }

}
```

El caso es que lo he intentado hacer al reves, osea que sea h1<0 && h1>24 y tampoco sale, y con el || el codigo sigue para adelante, alguna ayudita?

La clase entrada no la pongo porque no influye en el código, es una clase que tengo para leer las entradas un saludo. Pregunto aquí porque es el último sitio donde acudo un saludo

---

Como es un bucle do while, la linea h1=Integer.parseInt(horauno[0]);

siempre pasa entonces coje el valor de horauno[0] que siempre es 25. un saludo, y en este caso lo que hay dentro del if es con el && (and)

Answer (score 0):

tu condicional esta bien,suponiendo que ingreses `25:10:15` `h1` sera igual a `25` al solicitarte un nuevo numero entre 0 y 23 tu podrías colocar `13` como nuevo valor de `h1` pero como estas dentro de un bucle este volverá al inicio donde `h1` es igual `horauno[0]=25` lo cual se repetirá constantemente ...

```
do {
     h1=Integer.parseInt(horauno[0]);//h1 sera igual a 25
     if (h1>=0 && h1<=23  ) {
     correcto=true;
     } else {
       System.out.println("La hora (1) tiene que estar comprendida entre 0 y 23");
       h1=Entrada.entero();
     }
   } while (correcto!=true);//se repite el bucle h1=25 otra vez
```

solución
lo que debes hacer es cambiar el valor en el `array` `horauno[0]` mas no en la variable h1

```
    System.out.println("Hora 1 ");
    hora1=Entrada.cadena();
    horauno=hora1.split(":");
     do {
        h1=Integer.parseInt(horauno[0]);
        if (h1>=0 && h1<=23  ) {
            correcto=true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("La hora (1) tiene que estar comprendida entre 0 y 23");
                horauno[0]=Entrada.cadena();
            }
        } while (correcto!=true);



    System.out.println("Hora 2 ");
    hora2=Entrada.cadena();
    horados=hora2.split(":");
    
     do {
        h2=Integer.parseInt(horados[0]);
        if (h2>=0 && h2<=23  ) {
            correcto=true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("La hora (2) tiene que estar comprendida entre 0 y 23");
                horados[0]=Entrada.cadena();
            }
        } while (correcto!=true);
```